# Access declaring object in Dart lambda

Tags: object, lambda, dart

How do I access the object I am declaring with a lambda, inside the lambda?
E.g.

```
final Marker marker = Marker(
  position: LatLng(
    center.latitude + sin(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
    center.longitude + cos(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
  ),
  onDragEnd: (LatLng newPosition) async {
    print('Old position: ${marker.position}');
  },
);
```

gives error: `Local variable 'marker' can't be referenced before it is declared.`

And

```
print('Old position: ${position}');
```

gives error: `Undefined name 'position'.`

Answer (score 0):

Quite frankly you can't do this. As the error states you cannot reference the variable `marker` before it has been declared. This makes sense because you are trying to reference a pointer to an object that hasn't been been constructed and therefore has no pointer pointing to it.

I would think about why exactly you need to reference the the `marker` variable inside one of it's constructor parameters. You may be trying to work against the design of the object using the lambda. If you decide you really need to access the marker's data inside the lambda, you could try wrapping the Marker in a factory like this:

```dart
class MarkerFactory {
  Marker _marker;
  Marker buildMarker() => _marker ??= Marker(
    position: LatLng(
      center.latitude + sin(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
      center.longitude + cos(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
    ),
    onDragEnd: (LatLng newPosition) async {
      print('Old position: ${marker.position}');
    },
  );
}
```

Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: "My" (actually, flutter's) workaround is to use object id to locate it in the list :/